# Laravel back()->withInput(); not working

Tags: laravel, redirect, authentication

I am currently following a video tutorial on a login form. Here's the code used in case Auth::attempt() fails:

```
return back()->withInput();
```

This should return the user to the form and fill out the inputs again (email, password). However the fields stay empty, while login is working correctly.

How can I fix this?

This is my form:

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'handleLogin')) !!}
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            {!! Form::text('email', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'EMail')) !!}
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            {!! Form::password('password', array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Password')) !!}
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <div class="checkbox icheck">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox"> Remember Me
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col -->
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                {!! Form::token() !!}
                {!! Form::submit(null, array('class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat')) !!}
            </div>
            <!-- /.col -->
        </div>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Edit: Found out that the following code I have works for login but the else statement is not executed when the login credentials are wrong. why?

```
public function handleLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, User::$login_validation_rules);
        $data = $request->only('email', 'password');
        if(\Auth::attempt($data)){
            return redirect()->intended('home');
        }else {
            return back()->withInput();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What Laravel version are you using?

Comment: @TiagoRL I am using Laravel 5.2. Also edited my question with something I found out.

Comment: If any of the `$this->validate()` rules fails, you will be instantly redirected back. Add the code contained in this section of the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors. If anything is displayed, it means that the validate() is being triggered, and that's why the code doesn't reach the `else`. I can't say for sure because I don't know what rules you've defined.

Comment: Also, about the input, in any case, by default, Laravel already sends back the input, so, you could try adding `old('email')` and see if it works. `{!! Form::text('email', old('email'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'EMail')) !!}`

Comment: @TiagoRL Had this code already added. Not getting any errors. These are my rules: `'email' => 'required|email|exists:users',
      'password' => 'required'`. old() istn't sadly working either. thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there any chance that you are using the `web` middleware group in this route? In a more recent version of Laravel 5.2.39, it is known that if you use that middleware group, session variables will be messed up. Try removing or adding that to your routes, depending on your case. You can see how to use the group here: https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware#middleware-groups

Comment: oh wow.... yes I was using that group. thank you very much! It's working know. what's the difference between using that group and don't using it?

Comment: Apparently in an update made to the framework, this group is added by default to all routes, and if you add it again errors and session vars stop behaving properly. Why exactly I wouldn't know. In previous revisions of Laravel 5.2, you had to add it manually in order to get sessions working. That issue happened to me too. It was quite confusing.

Comment: @resmall, how to remove `web` middleware? somehow I cannot find good solution in the internet. In the doc it is described how to add it but not how to remove it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, as we discussed, the problem is the `web` middleware. In previous revisions of the Laravel 5.2 framework, if you wanted to enable sessions and error variables, you had to wrap the routes in the `web` middleware.

As of version `5.2.27`, this is not the case anymore, since that middleware group is already applied to all routes, by default.

Knowingly, having version `5.2.27` or later, and using the web middleware group, causes issues with those same variables, common issues are session variables not being passed around, and the `$errors` variable provided by the class `\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession`, that is returned by the Laravel validation API is set, but empty**.

**Summary**

- If you have **Laravel 5.2.27 and later**, you don't need to wrap the routes in the `web` middleware group.
- **If the version is lower than that**, then you are required to do so, in order to use session variables and get validation errors.

**Sources**

- https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13313
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware#middleware-groups

Comment: This is how every answer should be. Solid and with good explanation

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, Laravel comes with web and api middleware groups that contains common middleware you may want to apply to web UI and your API routes:
App/Http/Kernal.php

```
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'auth:api',
    ],
  ];
```

Take a look at `web` which contains  `StartSession` and `ShareErrorsFromSession` which are responsible for session handling so if you want to show validation errors or persist old data then you have to include them in your middleware group. in this case its `web`.

Answer (score -1):

You Have To make the condiotion if The form has been back with `errors`, it should been fill out.

The `{{old('nom')}}` function look for **The Previous Filled Value** for a given field and echo it.

you can use it as below:

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <input type="text" 
           class="form-control form-control-sm @error('nom') is-invalid @enderror" 
           id="nom"
           name="nom"
           placeholder="Ecriver le nom votre ecole "
           value="{{old('nom')}}"
           >
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

try changing

```
return back()->withInput();
```

with

```
return redirect()->back()->withInput(\Input::all()
```

Comment: `back()` is the same as `redirect()->back()` as you can see in Laravel's source code. Also `withInput()` does the same as `withInput(\Input::all())`.